# Flutter Package(Cloud Firestore and URL Launcher) Errors while debugging Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an app in flutter which has the below errors while debugging.Has anyone faced anything similar with these packages?I did not find anything useful on the github pages to resolve this.
Is it ok to publish an app to the store having the below errors if the app seems to be running fine?

**Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.1.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.**

**Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.**

Comment: can you post your code screen image with terminal

Comment: Well right now I am not able to reproduce it but I am using the following packages and have mentioned the errors in the question.
url_launcher: ^5.5.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7

Comment: well fine,i think the class inside your imported external package is deprecated ,i think the package may be updated with new class and functionality, i hope you are using https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/versions/5.5.0.if yes please update your pubspec.yaml file: